# NSFetchedResultsController performFetch on background thread

Tags: core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I have to perform a fetch via `NSFetchedResultsController` on a background thread.

My current solution is structured like that:

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("backgroundfetching", NULL);

dispatch_async(fetchQueue,^{
    // 1. Create NSManagedObjectContext
    // 2. Create NSFetchRequest
    // 3. Create NSFetchedResultsController
    // 4. PerformFetch

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [[self table] reloadData];
    });
});

dispatch_release(fetchQueue);
```

My first tests ran well but is that the appropriate way?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803205/nsfetchedresultscontroller-fetch-in-a-background-thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the fetched results controller is intended to control the data that defines a tableview, it belongs on the foreground thread/operation that the UI runs on. It's rather pointless to put it on a background thread as you would lose all the advantages of using it in the first place.

I would also be concerned about the effects of sending the FRC delegate messages across asynchronous threads. I'm not sure how reliable that would be.

Having said all that, the sketch of your implementation looks fine as far as it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I agree with you regarding the FRC delegate, it's maybe not the best solution. Anyway, do you have an alternative suggestions for heavy fetching in background?

Comment: The primary advantages of a FRC are... (1) change tracking (2) caching and (3) conveniences in implementing UITableViewDataSource methods. In regards to (1), if an object in the FRC's Managed Object Context has change so that it would be removed, added or changed in respect to the FRC results (based on the FRC's current fetch request), the FRC delegate is notified of these details (allowing you to reload the table, etc.). If you do not need any of these features for your background thread you can probably just perform a fetch instead.

Comment: Fetched results controllers are married to table views. A fetched results controller is a controller object for mediating access to a set of fetch results - pretty much as the name says.

Comment: Oops, that should say AREN'T. Fetched results controllers AREN'T married to table views.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is something fundamentally wrong with this approach, as you're sharing managed objects across threads (you're fetching objects on one thread and referencing them on your main thread). In practice it will work, but will sometimes lead to crashes. Because Apple makes it clear that the only ways to share managed objects across threads is using the objectWithID: method or the MOCDidSave notifications.

From the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html):

> You fetch in one managed object context on a background thread, and
>   pass the object IDs of the fetched objects to another thread. In the
>   second thread (typically the application's main thread, so that you
>   can then display the results), you use the second context to fault in
>   objects with those object IDs (you use objectWithID: to instantiate
>   the object).

Comment: But how would you do this with a `NSFetchedResultsController`? You cannot send ObjectIDs to a fetched results controller, or can you?

Comment: I believe NSFetchedResultsController is meant to be used from the main thread. I wouldn't be surprised that it has some internal optimizations that pre-fetches the data from a bg thread and then passes the objects to the main thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not sufficient to deal with the performance issues outlined here.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I think you __can__ send objectIDs to a fetch request. You can use a predicate along the lines of `@"self IN(%@)", objectIDs`

Comment: I presume you mean "send to a fetched results controller". OK, but the whole heavy lifting with sorting and grouping, sectionNameKeyPath etc. is not saved...

Comment: Well, you got to feed your fetched results controller some fetch request. The predicate can be the objectIDs, and you can still add a sort descriptor on top of that. You'll still be able to give the NSFRC a `sectionNameKeyPath` regardless of your fetch request predicate.

Comment: Ahh I get what you mean. Yeah all of these things won't be included with the passing of the object IDs, so CoreData will have to re-process them. Have you benchmarked your fetch request? Is the sorting/grouping really the chokehold? I would have thought it would be the querying itself.

Comment: Difficult to say. I tried looking at it in Instruments, but that itself slows things down and does not yield very useful results. Timestamps in NSLog are also problematic with threaded code...

Comment: Sure. It has its own fetch module, so that seemed promising. Yes, the fetches are taking most of the time.

Comment: I just tried that `@"self IN(%@), objectIds` idea. It works, but for me on an iPhone 4/iOS6 with our database the result is 3 times slower.