# Fetching from DB using NSFetchedResultsController causes app freezes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my app there was a freezing issue while handling large data from server. I was really confused about the issue, At Last i have tried background saving of coredata using Parent-Child strategy. After that the app become little more faster than earlier but small freezing is still there. So I'm thinking that Now the issue may be because of fetching Core data. So is there any way to do fetching coredata in background ? 
I was already searched the link 
[NSFetchedResultsController: Fetch in a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803205/nsfetchedresultscontroller-fetch-in-a-background-thread)

But that links doesn't helped me.

```
   -(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController
 {


if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSString *loginUser=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"currentUser"];

AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ThreadInfo"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"threadDate" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];


NSPredicate *threadPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userEmail == %@",loginUser];
// NSPredicate *providerPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isReceiver == YES"];
//  NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[threadPredicate, providerPredicate]];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:threadPredicate];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:5];
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

**Appdelegate**

```
         - (void)saveContext
 {
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();

  }
 }
 }

  #pragma mark - Core Data stack


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
 {


if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}


NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    //        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext;

 }

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

   NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"IXCoreDataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
  _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
  return _managedObjectModel;
}


- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
  {

 if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]   URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inxed.sqlite"];

 NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    /*
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

 #pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
   - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
    {

   return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory   inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

  }
```

While freezing i found issue in the line (below) by pausing the app.

```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

   {
    ThreadInfo *info=[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];// THIS LINE TAKES TOO MUCH TIME


if([info.isSystemMessage boolValue]){

    return 178+90+25;


} else {
     return 300;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't help you how? Have you done any profiling to find your performance issues?

Comment: Updated question with the line that causes freezing.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803205/nsfetchedresultscontroller-fetch-in-a-background-thread

Comment: I have already checked that code, but you know i am newbie, it was more confused me. All I want is how to modify the "fetchedResultsController" method to handle background fetching?

Comment: Stop wanting a background thread. Look at using estimated heights instead.

Comment: No, Actullay i need     ThreadInfo *info=[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];// THIS LINE TAKES TOO MUCH TIME
Its not possible to find the height without that line.

Comment: Why are you using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType?

Answer (score 0):

You are handling *large data* but fetch all data at once and don't limit it to a useful amount. So in the initialising of your `NSFetchedResultsController` you may not need to fetch real objects, use the faults, they are mostly ok.

`// FRC request
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = YES;// redundant, I only want to make this clear
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20; // or even less, depending on your amount of data visible to the user`

Then, as [Wain said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538308/fetching-from-db-using-nsfetchedresultscontroller-causes-app-freezes/29556083#comment47230098_29538308), use `estimated height`. This allows the FRC to guess a rough section of your data to look at and when the real height is calculated (as you did) the data is at hand.

Next thing: indexed data. Is your `isSystemMessage` indexed? It should be.