# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and PrivateQueueConcurrency

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I've been reading that if you use a context with a Private Queue Concurrency type, a FetchedResultsController with that context will call its delegate methods on that private queue also.  (ex. [here](http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/93190211147/secrets-of-nsfetchedresultscontroller-happiness) which is linked in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803205/nsfetchedresultscontroller-fetch-in-a-background-thread)).

I've tested this and my view controller (the FRC delegate) is receiving these calls on the main thread.  Just curious if anyone has the definitive answer on this.

I'm creating and calling the MO context and the FRC on the main thread. my -performBlock calls on the context only make some model changes and save - they don't touch the UI or dispatch anything to the mainQueue

**EDIT:** Specifically, is the quote below correct; i.e. do we need to implement
the FRC delegate methods using calls to the main queue

> NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate callbacks will now come from the context’s queue. Any user interface updates you do as a result need to be dispatched to the main queue:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController*) controller {
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}];
```

}

Comment: In the question you reference it is explained explicitly that this works only if you perform the fetch of the FRC in the background context, **not** on the main thread.

Comment: yep, the fetch and save are done in a -performBlock on the private context.  I edited to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If your fetched results controller delegate methods are implemented in a view controller they *should* be called on the main thread. Typically, a view controller controls a view and reacts to data changes to update the managed view which *par force* happens on the main thread.

If you "do not touch the UI", you should *not* use a view controller but some kind of abstract data manager class. Make sure the managed object context has a private queue concurrency type and that you make all calls (including the FRC's `performFetch`) via the block APIs.